# Neo4j labels, how to handle special characters?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and Cypher and could use some simple input on using special characters in node labels. Can someone clarify what's not allowed and suggest how to handle turning database headings with special characters into Cypher friendly labels.

IATI, one humanitarian reporting standard uses hyphens while another called HXL uses hashtags and plus signs. I'd like to make a node with multiple labels like (:reporting-org:#org+reporting) making a node for a reporting organization that can be queried via reporting-org or #org+reporting but I understand I can't use these special characters.

It this so? Any thoughts on how to make headings like reporting-org and #org+reporting cypher friendly?

Answer (score 4):

Escaping labels containing special characters with backticks should work e.g.

`reporting-org` and `#org+reporting`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Would using backticks impact querying? Can Cypher still differentiate between `#org+reporting` and `#org+funding`?

Comment: Yes, they're both distinct labels if escaped. Don't believe there's any impact on querying

Comment: Though the OpenCypher style guide advises against it https://github.com/opencypher/openCypher/blob/master/docs/style-guide.adoc
I'd map these to more readable labels if possible